# Returning EDT arrays from method and retrieving it, AX 2012

Tags: arrays, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have fiddled with this problem for a while and can't seem to find the solution. I'm working on some code another guy originally wrote, my job is to get it to work since he didn't get the possibility to finish it.

I have created an EDT called MpasMthSalesIndex with array elements containing all the months, Jan - Dec.

I make a call to the method (which is in the MpasItemSales datasource) below from a form to get the array returned like this:

```
[MpasMthSalesIndex] = MpasItemSales.MthSales(Year(today())-2);
```

giving me the error: "operand types are not compatible with the operator"

it doesn't work. this was what the original code was, and i have tried everything i can come up with to get this array returned. Anyone know how i can do this?

HERE'S THE METHOD I CALL:

What i do is initializing the MpasMthSalesIndex Ret, and fill it with values and try to return it, no errors here, but I get errors when i try to assign it to MpasMthSalesIndex from the form where i need it...

```
MpasMthSalesIndex MthSales(Yr _yr)
{
    int     i;
    int     m;
    date    d = SystemDateGet();
    date    e;
    Qty                 YrSales[366];
    MpasMthSalesIndex   ret;
    ;

    switch(_yr)
    {
        case(Year(d))                         :     [YrSales] = this.MpasSalesCurYr;
                                                    d = dateStartYr(d);
                                                    break;
        case(Year(PrevYr(d)))                 :     [YrSales] = this.MpasSalesPrevYr;
                                                    d = dateStartYr(PrevYr(d));
                                                    break;
        case(Year(PrevYr(PrevYr(d))))         :     [YrSales] = this.MpasSalesPrev2Yr;
                                                    d = dateStartYr(PrevYr(PrevYr(d)));
                                                    break;
        case(Year(PrevYr(PrevYr(PrevYr(d))))) :     [YrSales] = this.MpasSalesPrev3Yr;
                                                    d = dateStartYr(PrevYr(PrevYr(PrevYr(d))));
                                                    break;
    }

    e = dateEndYr(d);
    while (d<e)
    {
        i = DayOfYr(d);
        m = MthOfYr(d);
        ret[m] += YrSales[i];
        d++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
[MpasMthSalesIndex] = MpasItemSales.MthSales(Year(today())-2);
```

is expecting a container as return value, as in:

```
int a, b, c;
[a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Try to edit the method to return a container:

```
return [ret];
```

Comment: that did not work. however if it is like this 
MpasMthSalesIndex[0] = MpasItemSales.MthSales(Year(today())-2); it won't give any errors, but in the method i give a value to every single month/array-element and i need all of these.

But i would think if it is an EDT with array elements it would return the whole array if you just a instance of it's type. i just can't get such a simple thing to work

Comment: Then return a container instead, `return [ret]` and revert to `[MpasMthSalesIndex] = MpasItemSales.MthSales(Year(today())-2);`

Comment: it seemed to work doing this with a small work around. Thanks a bunch, Jan! :D